# How to realize vim visual block and multicuror operation with VScode and Vim extention

Tags: visual-studio-code

How should I set the config files for VScode and Vim extention to do the operation below in MacOS ? step1: select a part of codes with vim visual block. step2:put the key, "cmd + shift + L" in order to enter the multi-cursor mode for VScode. step3: after it forcus the codes I want to choose, put the key, "i" for vim, meaning of starting editing them. That's all. But now my enviroment makes me back to normal mode on putting "i" key just between transition from step2 to step3, leading to that I cannot enter the edit mode. Please tell me why and how to fix.

Described above.

tep1: select a part of codes with vim visual block. step2:put the keys, "cmd + shift + L" in order to enter the mode, multi-cursor for VScode. step3: after it forcus the codes I want to edit, put the key, "i" for vim, meaning of starting editing. That's all.